# "Illegal polymorphic or qualified type" in Control.Lens

Tags: haskell, lenses, haskell-lens

I'm working with `Control.Lens`. The actual function I'm writing is rather complex, but for the purpose of this question, I've boiled it down to a minimal failing example:

```
import Control.Lens    

exampleFunc :: Lens s t a b -> String
exampleFunc _ = "Example"
```

This fails to compile, yielding the following error message:

```
Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: Lens s t a b
Perhaps you intended to use -XRankNTypes or -XRank2Types
In the type signature for `exampleFunc':
  exampleFunc :: Lens s t a b -> String
```

Why is this illegal? It seems awfully similar to the following, which *does* compile:

```
import Data.Maybe

exampleFunc' :: Maybe (s, t, a, b) -> String
exampleFunc' _ = "Example"
```

So I'm assuming the difference lies in the definition of `Lens`. But what about the `Lens` type makes `exampleFunc`'s type illegal? I have a sneaking suspicion it has to do with the `Functor` qualification in the definition of `Lens`, but I could be wrong. For reference, the [definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-1.2/docs/Control-Lens.html) of `Lens` is:

```
type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

So, do I have to somehow satisfy the `Functor` qualification in my definition of `exampleFunc`? If so, how? I'm not seeing where in my type signature I have the opportunity to declare this constraint. Or maybe I'm on the wrong track, and my problem has nothing to do with the `Functor` constraint.

I've read all the Stack Overflow questions I could find regarding the "illegal polymorphic etc" error message. Perhaps this is my lack of familiarity with Haskell showing, but I can't see any of those questions being applicable to my current situation.

Nor have I been able to find any documentation on what the error message means in general.

Comment: `RankNTypes` is one of the extensions you can safely switch on when the compiler suggests so. This is ok for many other extensions too, though perhaps not for `OverlappingInstances` & `IncoherentInstances`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lens uses rank 2 types and you have it to the left of an arrow so to use any of lenses types like this you have to make it legal to even utter something like

```
(forall a. foo) -> bar
```

Which you can too with

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-} -- Rank2Types is a synonym for RankNTypes
```

at the top of your file. Without it, it's illegal to even use a lens type synonym since they use a part of the language you must enable.

Comment: That's not what negative position means. For example, in `(a -> r) -> r`, `a` appears in positive position.

Comment: @BenMillwood It's a simplified version, and yes the negative and positive positions behave like multiplication, in that the negative position of a negative position is a positive position. But for this instance I felt a simplified description was sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

`exampleFunc` fails to compile because the `Lens` type synonym is polymorphic and occurs in the signature in what is called "negative position", that is, to the left of the `->`.

You can use `Lens` in a type signature even without having `RankNTypes` on. This typechecks:

```
import Control.Lens

lensy :: Lens' (a,b) a 
lensy = _1
```

But this fails to typecheck:

```
oops :: Lens' (a,b) a -> Int
oops = const 5
```

Why? For the same reason this also fails to typecheck without `RankNTypes`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}

fails :: (forall a. a -> Int) -> Int
fails = undefined
```

Here the `forall` is in negative position, and ranges only over the `a -> Int`. It is the *implementation* of `fails`, and not the *caller* of `fails`, the one who chooses the type of `a`. The caller must supply an argument function that works for all `a`. This feature [requires the RankNTypes extension](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/explicit-forall).

When the `forall` ranges over the whole signature (as when `Lens` is defined in isolation) there's no need for `RankNTypes`. This typechecks:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}

typechecks :: forall a. (a -> Int) -> Int
typechecks = undefined
```

But this function is different from the previous one, because here it is the *caller* who chooses the type of `a`. He can pass an argument function which works only for a particular `a`.

`exampleFunc'` worked because, when no `forall` is specified, there are implicit `foralls` for each variable, ranging over the whole signature.

[This explanation](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2008-May/043581.html) from the Haskell mailing list may be useful.